# Auto Mapping errors to individual properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper, tinymapper

If I have an auto mapper such as TinyMapper or ExpressMapper configured to map DTOs to Models, and my DTO has notified me that, for example 'myDto.Email' has failed to update, is there a way to map that property back to the model (specifically in my case for ModelState.AddModelError purposes).

Here's a little pseudo code to hopefully clarify my need:

```
var mapper = SomeMapper.Register<MyModel, MyDto>();

var myDto = mapper.Map(myModel)
var errors = myDto.Update()
if(errors.Any())
{
  var error = errors.First();
  var property = memberConfiguration.GetMeTheModelPropertyFor(dto => dto.PropertyName= error.Property)

  ModelState.AddModelError(property.Name, error.Message);
}
```

So basically I'm asking which mapper can I achieve something like `GetMeTheModelPropertyFor` above and how?

Comment: I don't get why you want to do this. Isn't the error property enough?

Comment: Hi, No not really, as the error property is coming from the domain so may have a different name to the model, ie dto.CustomerEmail but domain.Email, so @Html.ValidationMessage' will not associated the domain error with a model property without mapping.

Comment: you can create a custom mapping https://github.com/TinyMapper/TinyMapper/wiki/Custom-mapping

Comment: @GSerjo, mapping the properties isn't a problem, its getting to the property details so I can resolve a domain string representation of property (i.e. "CustomerEmail") to a domain property "Email" (for use in MVC methods like ModelState.AddModelError).